# Webcomponents Polyfills - Order of execution

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, polyfills, custom-element

I'm currently trying to load a js file with web components via a dynamic script. The js file contains the webcomponents-lite polyfill too. The problem I'm running into is that the js file will work in IE 11 only if it gets loaded before the DOMContentLoaded event is fired.  If it gets loaded and executed after DOMContentLoaded, my components don't work. Is this expected behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: thanks for the help, i ended up using the polyfill here: https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element rather than the one hosted by webcomponents. I found it better in the following ways: fixed my problem above, smaller polyfill size, easier integration with es6 classes transpiled to es5.

Comment: Custom Elements has upgraded to v1 and you should be using [`customElements.define`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements) instead of `document.register`